# Java FX update one TextField based on another TextField value

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to JAVA FX, I want to 'live' update one TextField based on another TextField value.

This is my snippet code:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
tf_code.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        System.out.println(newValue.substring(2, 6));
        tf_newCode.setText(newValue.substring(2, 6));
    });

  }
```

Should I add another listener to my second TextField ?

Comment: No, why would you? (Unless there's something about the desired behaviour you didn't post in the question.) You only need to add a listener to the field that you want to base the changes of the other field on. What you do need to do though is dealing a strings with a length less than 6 chars. Is that what you're having trouble with, i.e. do you see exceptions in the console with a `Caused by IndexOutOfBoundsException` as part of the stacktrace?

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem, this snippet looks like it should work, are you getting some kind of exception or is field simply not updating?

Comment: Hi @Filip field simply not updating

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Note that the below code does not require a `.fxml` file. Perhaps the call to method `substring()` in the code you posted is throwing an `Exception` that you are unaware of because you are catching it in an empty `catch` block? Of-course I'm only guessing since you only posted part of your code.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JfxTst00 extends Application {
    public void start(Stage mainStage) throws Exception {
        mainStage.setTitle("JfxTst00");
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        TextField tf_NewCode = new TextField();
        TextField tf_Code = new TextField();
        tf_Code.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldVal, newVal) -> tf_NewCode.setText(newVal));
        root.setTop(tf_Code);
        root.setBottom(tf_NewCode);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 220, 70);
        mainStage.setScene(scene);
        mainStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your questions does not actually explain the problem you're facing, though I see a few that you **should** be having.

First of all, you only need one listener for the first `TextField` because that is the one we are watching for changes.

Then you need to account for input into the `TextField` that is less than 2 characters and more than 6. Since you have set hard limits in your `subString(2, 6)` call, we only want our listener to work within those constraints.

Here is a simple text application that demonstrates:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFieldBinding extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        TextField txt1 = new TextField();
        TextField txt2 = new TextField();

        txt1.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

            // First, only update txt2 if the new value entered in txt1 is greater than 2, otherwise
            // our substring() method will throw an exception
            if (newValue.length() > 2) {

                // We also need to prevent trying to get a substring that exceeds the remaining length
                // of the txt1 input
                int maxIndex;
                if (newValue.length() < 6) {
                    maxIndex = newValue.length();
                } else {
                    maxIndex = 6;
                }

                // Now set the text for txt2
                txt2.setText(newValue.substring(2, maxIndex));
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(txt1, txt2);

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```